# how to delete a message after a function is run using discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am doing a music search command for my bot and I am trying to delete a message after I finish in a different function.

I tried this but it does not delete it. It comes up with an unknown message.

```js
const search = require('yt-search')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message ,args ,ops) =>{

message.delete()

search(args.join(' '), function(err, res) {

    if(err) return message.channel.send("Sorry, something went wrong.")

    let videos = res.videos.slice(0, 10);

    let resp = '';

    let resp = '';

    let n

    for( var i in videos){
        resp += `**[${parseInt(i)+1}]:**\`${videos[i].title}\`\n `
    }

    resp += `\n**Choose a number between \` 1-${videos.length}\`**`

    message.channel.send(resp).then(msg =>{
        n = msg.id
    })

    const filter = m => !isNaN(m.content) && m.content < videos.length +1 && m.content > 0;

    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter);

    collector.videos = videos

    collector.once("collect", function(m, n){

       message.channel.fetchMessages(n).then(mess =>mess.delete());   

       let commandFile = require(`./play.js`)
       commandFile.run(bot, message, [this.videos[parseInt(m.content)-1].url], ops)
    })
```

Comment: Not enough code in here to tell what everything is. Example: What is `message`

Comment: it would be helpful to see what error you get, how the message object is defined, and how search is defined

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shown, there is little context on the message variable. The fact that it's unknown and you send a function as callback makes me think of the scope of that function. One thing you could try is to change the function here:

```
collector.once("collect", function(m,n){

           message.channel.fetchMessages(n).then(mess =>mess.delete());   

            let commandFile = require(`./play.js`)
            commandFile.run(bot, message, [this.videos[parseInt(m.content)-1].url], ops)
        })
```

to an arrow function:

```
collector.once("collect", (m,n) => {
   // rest of the code 
});
```

Comment: When i change it. I got a error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined`.

Comment: @WilliamAndrews try changing `this.videos` to `videos`.

Comment: Nope i got different error ` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message`